# Linux' hrtimer - microsecond precision?

Tags: linux, timer, module, kernel, real-time

Is it possible to execute tasks on a Linux host with microsecond precision? I.e., I'd like to execute a task at a specific instant of time. I know, Linux is no real-time system but I'm searching for the best solution on Linux.

So far, I've created a kernel module, setup hrtimer and measured the jitter when the callback function is entered (I don't really care too much about the actual delay, it's jitter that counts) - it's about 20-50us. That's not significantly better than using timerfd in userspace (also tried using real-time priority for the process but that did not really change anything).

I'm running Linux 3.5.0 (just an example, tried different kernels from 2.6.35 to 3.7), /proc/timer_list shows hrtimer_interrupt, I'm not running in failsafe mode which disables hrtimer functionality. Tried on different CPUs (Intel Atom to Core i7).

My best idea so far would be using hrtimer in combination with ndelay/udelay. Is this really the best way to do it? I can't believe it's not possible to trigger a task with microsecond precision. Running the code in kernel space as module is acceptable, would be great if the code was not interrupted by other tasks though. I dont' really care too much about the rest of the system, the task will be executed only very few times a second so using mdelay/ndelay for burning the CPU for some microseconds every time the task should be executed would not really matter. Altough, I'd prefer a more elegent solution.

I hope the question is clear, found a lot of topics concerning timer precision but no real answer to that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want from user space

1. use [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` to get the time-of-day with `nano`-second resolution
2. use [`nanosleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nanosleep) to yield the CPU until you are close to the time you need to execute your task (it is at least `milli`-second resolution).
3. use a spin loop with `clock_gettime()` until you reach the desired time
4. execute your task

The `clock_gettime()` function is implemented as a [`VDSO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) in recent kernels and modern x86 processors - it takes 20-30 `nano`seconds to get the time-of-day with `nano`-second resolution - you should be able to call `clock_gettime()` over 30 times per `micro`-second.  Using this method your task should dispatch within 1/30th of a `micro`-second of the intended time.

Comment: Altough not entirely sure if a userspace solution will solve my problem so far, this solutions solves the problem of executing tasks at microsecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

The default Linux kernel timer ticks each millisecond. Microseconds is *way* beyond anything current user hardware is capable of.

The jitter you see is due to a host of factors, like interrupt handling and servicing higher priority tasks. You can cut that down somewhat by selecting hardware carefully, only enabling what is really needed. The real-time patchseries to the kernel (see the [HOWTO](http://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO)) might be an option to reduce it a bit further.

Always keep in mind that any gain has a definite cost in terms of interactiveness, stability, and (last, but by far not least) your time in building, tuning, troubleshooting, and keeping the house of cards from falling apart.

Comment: "Microseconds is way beyond anything current user hardware is capable of." I beg to differ - a 2GHz dinosaur of a processor ticks at 0.5 nsec intervals. If you assume an insanely high 10 clocks per instruction average, and an equally insanely high 50 instructions to implement a loop, that's still 250 nsec per loop, which means timing loops with much better than millisecond resolution are easily possible on modern hardware...

Comment: @twalberg, how many instructions does your CPU execute in a microsecond? A dozen?

Comment: The Pentium 4 hardware programmers reference seems to indicate the majority of commonly used instructions have a latency of well under 10 clocks, and that's from 2002. 10 clocks at 2GHz (modern CPUs run closer to twice that) is 5 nanoseconds - so most likely more than 200 instructions per microsecond. Obviously cache concerns and data hazards and other things can temper that somewhat, but a tight timing loop can run pretty fast...