# How can I execute a task at an exact rate of 4kHz in Linux (with PREEMPT-RT if necessary)

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel, real-time

In my embedded C code, I need to run a function at an accurate 4kHz rate to simulate some waveform. I am running some Linux 3.10 kernel with PREEMPT-RT patch. The question is very similar to this post:
[Linux' hrtimer - microsecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944204/linux-hrtimer-microsecond-precision)
But my particular question is: does the recent PREEMPT-RT kernel provide some user API or some more convenient way for such purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I have just come up with an alternative solution by using Xenomai framework. I built and installed the Xenomai in my Linux and installed Xenomai userspace support. Then there is a simple API rt_task_set_periodic allows you to schedule periodic task precisely.
Here is the example:
https://github.com/meeusr/xenomai-forge/blob/master/examples/native/trivial-periodic.c

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion.. no.
PREEMPT_RT only let the kernel be interrupted if needed. My personal opinion is to try to find a delay routine and trim it whit the oscilloscope.

I had a similar issue and I found that "sleep" and "usleep" are not so accurate, I ended up writing my own delay routine.

Hope this helps.